# File extension to file type checker in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I've created simple script to compare actual file type to extension. I don't know why I cannot search dictionary for key returned from `file.read(3)` . If I enter the key manualy or use `sig` like below, everything works fine.

```
file_sigs = {b'\xff\xd8\xff':('JPEG','.jpg'), b'\x46\x4f\x52':('GIF','.gif')}
file = open("ggg.jpg", "rb")
sig = file.read(3)
ext = os.path.splitext('ggg.jpg')[1]
if sig in file_sigs:
    #print(file_sigs[sig])
    if ext in file_sigs[b'\xff\xd8\xff'][1]:
        print('match')
    else:
        print('no match')
else:
    print('no such signature')
```

Comment: Searching the dictionary does work. You are referring to `print (file_sigs[sig])`? I commented that line and it outputs `('JPEG', '.jpg')\nmatch`. I'm on python3.6. Which python are you using?

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in using an existing solution: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

Comment: 7th line - I can do it either way, as above or like `if ext in file_sigs[sig][1]:` but not like `if ext in file_sigs[file.read(3)][1]:`

Comment: You mean `if ext in file_sigs[file.read(3)]: print('Matching extension:', ext)`. That works as well for me. I updated my answer

Comment: hmm, I got key error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/webpage/readfile.py", line 15, in <module>
    if ext in file_sigs[file.read(3)][1]:
KeyError: b'\xe0\x00\x10'` which is very confusing to me, why the same thing returns different values? Maybe it has something to position in tuple, in that case `[1]`. Sorry, I'm very new in Python and I have a lot of questions :)

Comment: Is this using your script or using the script in my answer?

Comment: mine, in 7th line

Comment: Keep in mind that you are not able to re-read the first 3 bytes after calling `file.read(3)`. You need to call `file.seek(0)` if you want to re-read the first 3 bytes. Look at the `KeyError: b'\xe0\x00\x10'`. You don't have that in your file_sigs dict. I bet that's reading bytes 4,5,6 since you've called `file.read(3)` before.

Comment: that make sense, thank you so much for explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side note: Calling `file.read(3)` will move the read head 3 bytes forward. So in order to re-read the file from some position `x` (including the start) you need to call `file.seek(x)`.

Is this what you're trying to do? This script works on python3.6. It's basically the same script as the one you have posted, but with some minor changes.

```
import os
from sys import argv

file_sigs = {
    b'\xff\xd8\xff': (
        '.jpeg',
        '.jpg'
    ),
    b'\x46\x4f\x52': (
        '.gif'
    )
}

file = open(argv[1], "rb")

ext = os.path.splitext(argv[1])[1]

if ext in file_sigs[file.read(3)]:
    print('Matching extension:', ext)
else:
    print('no such signature')
```

Output python2.7

```
↳ python2 a.py ggg.jpg 
('Matching extension:', '.jpg')
```

Output python3.6

```
↳ python a.py ggg.jpg 
Matching extension: .jpg
```